# Cannot modify top/bottom space for header/footer in LibreOffice, and disabled Header/Footer after export to Office 2007

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, libreoffice-writer, headers, margins

I have written my Thesis in LibreOffice. Everything is fine, but my University requires to provide the Thesis in a very specific format. In LibreOffice I cannot replicate the "From Top/From Bottom" space for header/footer. As a result the template is wrong and I need to fix it.

So, I saved the document as MS Word 2003 (from the LibreOffice) and opened the *.doc from my Office 2007 Word. In MS office I cannot change the page boundaries and to edit/change the Header/Footer. Specifically, the Edit Header/Edit Footer options are disabled on the Ribbon.

How can I solve that?

Comment: This question addresses two different problems: (1) Setting the spacing in LibreOffice, and (2) modifying it in WinWord while controls are disabled. Both aspects would require an answer on its own, so it would be better to restrict the question to the main problem - that's (IMHO) the first one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you need to set the margin between the page border and the top of the Header to a certain value. You can achieve this easily in LibreOffice Writer, so you don't need to manipulate the document in MS Word.

There are different spacing values you can set:

- On the **Page** tab, you can set the **Top/Bottom margins of the entire page**. If you have a Header / Footer enabled, this is the margin between the physical "paper border" and the top border of the header) / the bottom  border of the footer respectively. The Header / Footer is placed **inside** the margins defined on the page tab:

  [image: Page Margins 1]
- On the **Header / Footer** tab, you can set the **height of the header / footer** and the **space between header / footer and main content**. Indirectly, these values determine the margin of the main page content to the "physical" page border:

  [image: Header margins]

  [image: Footer margins]

If there are certain, defined margins required, make sure **not to choose Dynamic Space / Auto fit height** on the Header / Footer tab.

So, the "big picture" looks like this (light yellow: main content; blue: header; green: footer):

[image]

`1a` , `b`, `c` and `d` are set on the **Page** tab; `2a/2b` and `3a/3b` on the **Header / Footer** tab respectively. The top margin of the "main content" area is the sum of `1c + 2a + 2b`; its bottom margin vice versa `1d + 3a + 3b`.